# Code comment with scheduled Git changeset

Tags: git, github-actions, githooks

I'm wondering if something like the code sample below is possible:

```ruby
val = calculate_method1()

# GIT-COMMAND-DELETE date="2022-05-23" msg="About time to delete it"
val = temporary_overriden__calculate_method1()
# GIT-COMMAND-DELETE

# GIT-COMMAND-ADD date="2022-05-29" msg="Something changed, fail from now on" delete-body-comment=true
# raise("By that time it had to be already fixed")
# GIT-COMMAND-ADD
```

Basically, it's a code comment with some sort of git command that needs to be executed automatically some time in the future and committed(e.g. as a feature-branch/pull-request).

Is there an existing Github Action for such need or any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a built-in solution in `git` alone.

---

I would place this kind of task in an issue tracker (e.g: "review that code by 2022-05-29") or have a delayed task (I'm thinking: outside of git) that sends a reminder at that date.

If you want your CI to trigger a flag : why not code it in your language, within a test ?

```
if (date() >= "2022-05-29") {
    raise("do we still use that overriden value ? it should have been fixed by now")
}
```